# Override Method in Laravel/Lumen Core Application

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Is it possible to override a function defined in the Laravel/Lumen `Application` class?

For example, this is the definition of `isDownForMaintenance` in the Lumen `Application` class:

```
public function isDownForMaintenance() : bool
{
    return false;
}
```

I would like to override this with my own implementation like so:

```
public function isDownForMaintenance() : bool
{
    // Do something…
}
```

## I have tried…

*AppServiceProvider.php*

```
$this->app->extend(‘app’, function () {
    return new Application; // Extension of Laravel/Lumen/Application
});
```

*Application.php*

```
class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    public function isDownForMaintenance() : bool
    {
        // Do Something…
    }
}
```

Comment: There is an other way to do it without overriding the method, with middlewares if you want !!

Comment: @Maraboc The problem with this is that this particular function is called from various places i.e. the QueueManager

Comment: I see with the milddleware it can't help :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After exploring throughout the web, I have managed to stumble upon an article that outlines **exactly** what I was looking for. For the purposes of simplicity, I will outline how to extend Laravel's & Lumen's core `Application` class, but for those of you who wish to see a more in depth description, please see here:

https://mattstauffer.com/blog/extending-laravels-application/

This is surprisingly, extremely easy... First, we find the place where `Application` is created i.e. `/bootstrap/app.php`

Then, we find the following line:

#### Laravel

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

#### Lumen

```
$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

And then quite simply change to this:

```
$app = new Custom\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
```

You can then do whatever you like with `Custom\Application', for instance;

```
class Application extends BaseApplication
{
    // Override the maintenance mode detection...
    public function isDownForMaintenance() : bool
    {
        // Do Something…
    }

    // Override the default storage path...
    public function storagePath()
    {
        return $this->basePath.'/custom/storage';
    }
}
```